# How to create an std::string from a malloc-ed one?

Tags: c++, c, string, malloc

My C++ code uses a C function, which returns a `malloc`-ed string (allocated by `asprintf`, actually). The rest of the C++ code uses `std::string`, so, currently, the interface looks like:

```
    string
    mycppfunction(.....)
    {
    ...
        char *cresult = theCfunction(....);
        string result = cresult;
        free(cresult);
        return result;
    }
```

The *copying* involved in creating `result` from `cresult` annoys me -- we already have a perfectly good buffer with the text we want, yet we copy it out (wasting time and risking `ENOMEM`) and then free it...

Is there a standards-blessed way of dealing with this pattern without such waste?

Comment: Perhaps what you need is [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead? You must still `free` the memory yourself when you're done with it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `string_view` won't manage the lifetime, and the intent here is to return an object from `mycppfunction`. So you'll need a parallel object like `std::unique_ptr` to manage the actual character array. Then the solution starts to stray far from using `std::string`.

Comment: You could also use *private* inheritance of `std::string_view` (to inherit the interface) for a class that contains a `std::unique_ptr` of the actual string data.